# Java reflection - how to call getter/setter method?

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to call set method of some property that I got in my object, my code goes like this:

```
    String[] fieldsStringName = (((CacheObject)currentObject).getFieldsToString(false)).split(", ");
    String methodName = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < objectInputArr.length; i++) {
        methodName = "set" + fieldsStringName[i];

        Method methodSetProperty = currentObject.getClass().getMethod(methodName);   <<----error occurs here
        methodSetProperty.invoke(currentObject, objectInputArr[i]);
    }
```

The error that i'm getting is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: model.Book.setPagesAmount()
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at CahceSystem.createNewObject(CahceSystem.java:84)
    at CahceSystem.main(CahceSystem.java:50)
```

The requested setter method is well written in the class and also in it's super class (inherited propeties only), all my setter's methods are like:

```
public void setPagesAmount(int pagesAmount) {
    this.pagesAmount = pagesAmount;
}
```

Any suggestions how to solve this issue?

Comment: what is the method's visibility? is it public?

Comment: updated in the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> currentObject.getClass().getMethod(methodName);
> ```

Since methods can be overloaded, just the *name* of the method is not enough to look up the method. You need to provide the types of the arguments as well (and a setter is typically not a no-arg method).

Try something like

```
currentObject.getClass().getMethod(methodName, objectInputArr[i].getClass());
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you my friend, was very helpful!

Comment: @RoeyGolzarpoor Take care of subclasses in your `objectInputArr` array. E.g. you have a `public class A`, a `public class B extends A`, and a `setA(A a)` method. An instance of `B` is a legal parameter value for `setA(A)`, but if you add a `B` object to `objectInputArr`, and use the suggested `getMethod(methodName, objectInputArr[i].getClass())`, you will get a `NoSuchMethodException`, as you will look for `setA(B)` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
*Field[] fields = currentObject.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

 for (Field field :fields) {
     Method method = student.getClass().getMethod("set"+field.getName()
    .replaceFirst(field.getName().substring(0, 1), field.getName()
    .substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()),field.getType());
}*
```

try the above snippet. its working fine